# Is it possible to inject test cases into soapui at runtime with test runner?

Tags: soap, soapui, test-runner

I am trying to determine whether I am able to inject test case information at run time and leverage the SOAPUI tool.  I understand that I can create test cases on the GUI but is this my only option?

Background info if interested: Currently I am working on creating an automation framework at my company. We currently have web page testing and soon to be added SOAP testing.  As many of these tests (at one point in the future as I am told my the architect) could be run from both a web page and soap I think it's best to store the test cases in some format (Json, YAML, etc.) to document all the test cases and then inject them into test steps at run time.

However my company enjoys working with SOAPUI. I've used the tool and created test cases, assertions, et al on the GUI (of course) but I cannot find any documentation which suggests that instead of defining the test cases in this way I could inject the test information at run time (similar to what you can do with the wsdl2java apache tool). Can this be done with testrunner? This way I can reuse the test cases.  Is this possible? Does this even make sense?  I just want to attempt to incorporate a tool I've been asked to use.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Here is an example of what data may look like:

Partner : [
    Organization : [
        Company Name:
        Company URL:
    ]
    Contact Information : [
        Name:
        Address:
    ]
]  (sorry i can't get the indents to work properly...)
 As I stated below in a comment, I know on the SoapUI GUI I can create a test suite, test case and add test steps.  But I want to store the test step information in a different place so I can use the test steps for different kinds of tests.

Comment: Anything is possible! Do you have a specific example in mind? Have you seen the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html

Comment: @SiKing i hope that anything is possible :).  Here is a simple example of what the data may look like:  Partner : [
 Organization : [
  Company Name:
  Company URL:
 ]
 Contact Information : [
  Name:
  Address:
 ]
]
 where the Name, address, et al are the points of interest for the test.  I know that I can go into the SoapUI GUI and create a test suite, test case and test steps. But what I"d like to do, instead of  storing the test step data in this fashion is have the data exist elsewhere. So I can use that data for different types of tests. Is this possible?  Do you know?

Comment: that didn't show up well... i will update my question

Comment: As I said: have you seen the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/datasources.html http://www.soapui.org/JDBC/getting-started.html

Comment: I had not but thank you sharing the last of three links. However I think the disconnect is I don't want to use the gui. I need it automated from a command line so these can run from Jenkins.  And the test data needs to be reusable and not just for soap ui. I apologize for not being specific in the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad for me to even attempt a complete answer.

SoapUI GUI you use to create the tests. Your data can be stored, and read by SoapUI, in Excel, database, flat file, generated dynamically, whatever you want. You can run everything using the testrunner from command line, or using the Maven plugin from Jenkins.

Seriously, spend some time with the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html).